# rewrite url to subdirectory on subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have all of my customers sites in a directory on my subdomain:

```
customers.example.com/sites/customer_name
```

I want to rewrite the url so my customers only need to write

```
customers.example.com/customer_name
```

I have tried some different `htacces` scripts but none of them works. And one of them gives me a `error 500 internal server error`, so my `mod_rewrite` is active

Here is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sites/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/$1/ [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rewrite engine loops, this pattern `^(.*)$` will blindly match everything, including your rule's target: `/sites/something`. It'll continue to append `/sites/` to the front of the URI until you end up with something like `/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/` etc.

You need to add some conditions to prevent the looping, something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/$1/ [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/$1/ [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sites%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sites%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: that worked :D. but now i have another issue, when i go to a joomla site, then the loop comes. I have tried to make a static site and there  the redirect works. i think i will make a new wuestion since it is out of topic

Answer (score 0):

This should work… If understand your end goal correctly. But unclear if you want the content accessible from `customers.example.com/sites/customer_name` and `customers.example.com/customer_name` at the same time:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/sites/(.*)$ http://customers.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: did not work, just gives me 404 page of my site, like there was no htaccces file. i have even runned your code thru a htacces tester, but that did not work.